# Conditional validation based on two dropdowns using JQuery Validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have spent hours trying to achieve the following validation using a custom validator method:

There are two dropdowns a user can select:

1. Current Location (Where user currently is)
2. Destination (Where user intends going)

**What I am trying to achieve:**
The validator should not allow a user to select the same location for both dropdowns except Location 1.

**For example:**
A user can select that he is going from Location 1 to Location 1. (Can travel to a different place in this location because this location is large).

But he cannot select that he is going from:
Location 2 to Location 2.
 
Location 3 to Location 3.
Location 4 to Location 4.
Location 5 to Location 5.
These locations do not have different places in the same location.

He can go from Location 1 to any of these other locations, vice-versa, or can go from Location to location, i.e Location 3 to Location 4.

Can you please help me out with this? What I have done so far is quite poor and not even working. The custom method is not working, I need to add rules and messages but do not know how.

Thanks in advance for any help!

What I have done so far:

HTML

```
<form id="rideForm" action="#">
<select id="3" name="currentLocation">
     <option value ="" class="inputDefault">Select Location</option>
          <option value="Location1">Location 1</option>
          <option value="Location2">Location 2</option>
          <option value="Location3">Location 3</option>
          <option value="Location4">Location 4</option>
          <option value="Location5">Location 5</option>
</select>

<select id="4" name="destination">
     <option value ="" class="inputDefault">Select Destination</option>
          <option value="Location1">Location 1</option>
          <option value="Location2">Location 2</option>
          <option value="Location3">Location 3</option>
          <option value="Location4">Location 4</option>
          <option value="Location5">Location 5</option>
</select>
</form
```

JS/JQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.validator.addMethod("validSelection", function(value, element) {
        if ($('select[name="currentLocation"]').val() == $('select[name="destination"]').val()) {
            return true;
      } else {
            return false;
    }
});


("#rideForm").validate(
{
    rules: 
    {   
        currentLocation:
        {
            required: true,
            // validSelection: true
        },

            destination: 
            {
                required: true,
            // validSelection: true
        }
    },



    messages: {
        currentLocation: {
            required: "Please select your current location",
        },


        destination: {
            required: "Please select a destionation",
        }
    }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this issue.

Here is the custom validator method to validate what has been described above for anyone doing something similar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.validator.addMethod("validSelection", function(value, element) {
        if ($('select[name="currentLocation"]').val() == "Location2" && $('select[name="destination"]').val() == "Location2") {
        return false;
    }
    else if ($('select[name="currentLocation"]').val() == "Location3" && $('select[name="destination"]').val() == "Location3") {
        return false;
    }
    else if ($('select[name="currentLocation"]').val() == "Location4" && $('select[name="destination"]').val() == "Location4") {
        return false;
    }
    else if ($('select[name="currentLocation"]').val() == "Location5" && $('select[name="destination"]').val() == "Location5") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});




$("#rideForm").validate(
{
    rules: 
    {
        currentLocation:
        {
            required: true,
        },

        destination: 
        {
            required: true,
            validSelection: true,

        }
    },

    messages: {

        currentLocation: {
            required: "Please enter your current location"
        },
        destination: {
            required: "Please enter a destionation",
            validSelection: "You cannot complete such a trip."
        }
    }
});

});
```

**EDIT:**

I have simplified the validator method code further. You can use this instead:

```
$.validator.addMethod("validSelection", function(value, element) {
    if ($('select[name="currentLocation"]').val() == "Location1" && $('select[name="destination"]').val() == "Location1") {
        return true;
    }
    else if ($('select[name="currentLocation"]').val() == $('select[name="destination"]').val() ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Cheers!